# Linear Combinations of vectors - Linear equations and combinations

Tags: linear-algebra

a) Determine a condition under which (x, y, z) is a linear combination of [-3, 5, -3], [-9, 11, -3], [-6, 8, -3]?
Your condition should take the form of a linear equation.

Im so confused?? I have the theorem that every vector (x, y, z) in R^3 is a linear combination of x(1, 0, 0) + y(0, 1, 0) + z(0, 0, 1).

Comment: Indeed for your last example you find that the combination always has solution for every x,y,z. But what if the given vectors are not linearly independent?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

In general we need to write down the system

$$av_1+bv_2+cv_3=(x,y,z)$$

in augmented matrix form and handle it by RREF to find the condition on x,y,z for the system to have solution.

Note that this approach gives the **cartesian equations** of the subspace spanned by $v_1,v_2,v_3$.

As an alternative look for the dimensions of the subspace, if you find dim=3 then the linear combination always has solution. Otherwise select a basis and solve the system for the basis vectors.